# has_many :through :uniq relationship needs to collect everything from the through table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Here's a problem that is kinda hard to explain. So here's an example. Let's say I have this in the model:

```
has_many :things,
  :through => :relationships,
  :source  => :thing
```

I need to get a list of `things` and whatever data I have on the `relationships` table. Let's say it's 'relationships.name'. We can do it like this:

```
has_many :things,
  :through => :relationships,
  :source  => :thing,
  :select  => 'things.*, relationships.name as rel_name'
```

So if there are 2 relationships present I'll get 2 objects back:

```
 #<Thing id: 1, rel_name: "foo">
 #<Thing id: 1, rel_name: "bar">
```

If we cram `:unique => true` or adjust select to use `DISTINCT` we'll get unique objects, but data about one of the relationships will be gone. What I really want are unique `things` with all different relationship names collected into an accessor:

```
 #<Thing id: 1, rel_names: ["foo", "bar"] >
```

Is there some dark SQL magic I'm not aware of that can do this? It's important for me to preserve the scope, so I can't just cycle through result set to collect that data.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has the [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) method for this sort of thing:

```
 has_many :things,
   :through => :relationships,
   :source  => :thing,
   :select  => 'things.*, GROUP_CONCAT(relationships.name as rel_name)'
```

Comment: Yes! Just missing the :group => 'things.id'

Answer (score 1):

using GROUP_CONCAT on MySQL:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :rel_names

  has_many :things,
    :through => :relationships,
    :source  => :thing,
    :select  => 'things.*, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT relationships.name SEPARATOR ";;") as rel_names'


  # .. your code ..

  def rel_names
    @rel_names.present? ? @rel_names.split(';;') : []
  end
end
```